# Architecture and Design Document for the next generation MapReduce

Tags: apache, hadoop, mapreduce

I would like to know the details (architecture and design documents) about the next generation Apache MapReduce. Where are the sources to get more information about it?

Comment: It's open source... go to http://hadoop.apache.org/mapreduce/#Getting+Involved and subscribe to the mailing list?

Comment: There are many open source frameworks/products discussed in the StackOverFlow and forums available for them. If we start using the forums for them, then what's the purpose of StackOverFlow?

I think StackOverFlow is a more efficient way to help each other than forums.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of Yahoo Blog entries on the next generation MapReduce Architecture.

http://developer.yahoo.com/blogs/hadoop/posts/2011/02/capacity-scheduler/

http://developer.yahoo.com/blogs/hadoop/posts/2011/02/mapreduce-nextgen/

http://developer.yahoo.com/blogs/hadoop/posts/2011/03/mapreduce-nextgen-scheduler/

then, there is a Video on YouTube at

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2FpO7w6X41I

The discussion on the next generation MapReduce Architecture can be found in the following JIRA

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MAPREDUCE-279

How to build and run next generation MapReduce can be found at

http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/hadoop/common/branches/MR-279/mapreduce/INSTALL

http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/hadoop/common/branches/MR-279/mapreduce/yarn/README

Answer (score 0):

It is the only serious explanation I know: 
http://developer.yahoo.com/blogs/hadoop/posts/2011/02/mapreduce-nextgen/